# Detect and select text like in Google Translate

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, image-recognition

Is there an API (javascript preferred) that I can use to detect words from an image and select them with fingers like in Google translate?

I'm not interested in translation but only in selecting a specific area of a photo and then retrieve all the words.

TIA

Davide

Comment: Google cloud vision?

Comment: Please consider share your conclusions and close the answer.